# (1) no such table from database, downloaded from URL

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a database on server as in-app purshase.
Downloading:

```
private static boolean downloadDatabase(Context context) {
    try {
           // Log.d(TAG, "downloading database");
            URL url = new URL("http://url/");
            /* Open a connection to that URL. */
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
            /*
             * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
             */
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            /*
             * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
             */
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                    baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            // Select storage location
            fos = context.openFileOutput(Global.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
           // Log.d(TAG, "downloaded");
    } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadDatabase Error: " , e);
            return false;
    }  catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadDatabase Error: " , e);
            return false;
    } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "downloadDatabase Error: " , e);
            return false;
    }
    return true;
```

This is DBHelper, where database is copying into data/data/... dir.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/mypackage/databases";
public static String DB_NAME = Global.getName();
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String SP_KEY_DB_VER = "db_ver";

private SQLiteDatabase db; 
private  Context context;

 public DBHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        initialize();
    }   

    private void initialize() {
        if (databaseExists()) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            int dbVersion = prefs.getInt(SP_KEY_DB_VER, 1);
            if (DB_VERSION != dbVersion) {
                File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
                if (!dbFile.delete()) {
                    Log.w("MY APP", "Unable to update database");
                }
            }
        }
        if (!databaseExists()) {
            createDatabase();
        }
    }

    private boolean databaseExists() {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
        Log.e("TAG","database exist?"+dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    /**
     * Creates database by copying it from assets directory.
     */
    private void createDatabase() {
        String parentPath = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getParent();
        String path = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
        File file = new File(parentPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (!file.mkdir()) {
                Log.w("MY APP", "Unable to create database directory");
                return;
            }
        }

        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = context.openFileInput(Global.getDictionary());
            os = new FileOutputStream(path);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            os.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (os != null) {
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        db= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(db != null)
                db.close();

            super.close();

    }




public String getStr() {
    databaseExists();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String s=null;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT indexStr from tablename where id=2 ",null);
    while (c.moveToNext()) {  
          s = c.getString(0);
    }  
    c.close();  
    db.close();  
    return s; 
}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
```

I see, that my app аfter downloading the database takes up more space of memory, but when I run any SELECT returns "(1) no such table", but database exists. May be database empty, but why? 
P.S. all permissions as WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE written.

Answer (score 0):

I think your table name is incorrect

```
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT indexStr from tablename where id=2 ",null);
```

the name of the table is really "`tablename`" ???

Check the value of

```
public static String DB_NAME = Global.getName();
```

probably you are reading a different Database!.

Comment: I write this like a example.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to the onCreate() method and see if the error goes off.

```
SQLiteDatabase db2 = openOrCreateDatabase("dbname", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db2.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name(row1 INT PRIMARY KEY, row2 VARCHAR, row3 VARCHAR, row4 VARCHAR, );");
```

If it does, that means your table was not created according to the way you tried before.

The best way for you to check if the database is populated, is by clicking on DDMS and checking if the database file is created under your project. If it is created, pull the file from the device, and viewing it through a SQLite DB browser like [SQLiteBrowser](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/releases)